# Error: Self-signed certificate, node.JS https client certificate authentication with request

Tags: node.js

I'd like to ask for your lights on the below:
Using nodeJS, I'm trying to establish https connection between my server, which acts as a client in this case and an external server. 
We want to use client certificate validation, and the external server has provided self-signed private.key and client.crt certificate.
My code is the below:

```
router.get('/mywebhook', function (req, res) {
console.log('/mywebhook');
var request = require("request");
//var options;
var options = { method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://externalserverURL'
    ,cert: fs.readFileSync('certs/client_crt.pem')
    ,key: fs.readFileSync('certs/key.pem')
}


request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error){
        //throw new Error(error);
        console.log(error);
        return res.end(error); 
    }
    console.log('all ok')
    return res.end(body);
});
```

});

I am getting though, the below error: 
**Error: self signed certificate
code: 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT'**

**Setting sst-strict = false is something I want to avoid.
Am I missing something? Any help?**

Comment: You can add self-signed SSL's crt file as trusted in server (in OS level not Node spesific configuration) that runnig node.js.

Answer (score 2):

You may either add extra root certificates to your server or you may do Node spesific configuration with environment variable.

- For Node to recognize your self signed certificate you may use NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS environment variable by giving path to file extra-ca-certs.pem file will make node add them :

```
env NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=./rootCA.crt node client.js
```

Comment: :Thanks for the reply.  I tried to provide the rootCA.pem but I still get the same error.

Comment: can you console.log(process.env.NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS) before request and ensure that new cert is set.